# Material Table Core - renderSummaryRow

Tags: reactjs, material-table

So im working with Material Table Core ONLY because it had the renderSummaryRow and it should have made things easy for me.

It turns out that the renderSummaryRow doesnt update when data changes, it always recieves the same data.

Any body has had this problem?

Comment: there isnt even a way to override the componente.